# Android: Fatal exception: main. What i do wrong?

Tags: java, android

I am beginer android developer. I want to get some data from server, method - Post.As i understand i need to do request, than i need to convert HttpEntity to string and then string to json. The code of activity file:

```
package com.example.earchive;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
/*** Work with login button ***/        
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_bt);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://go.earchive.ca/json/user.php");

                try 
                {
                    EditText email      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
                    EditText password   =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("em", email.getText().toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pa", password.getText().toString()));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

                        Log.d("My App", obj.toString());

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + result + "\"");
                    }                   



                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response));



            }
        });
/*** End of work with login button ***/         


        return true;


    }
}
```

The code of XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_2"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="5px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lettera" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scritta" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/white"

         />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Remember me"
        android:checked="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

```
02-11 10:19:10.378: D/dalvikvm(1302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 4% free 3327K/3452K, paused 31ms, total 33ms
02-11 10:19:10.788: D/gralloc_goldfish(1302): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-11 10:19:23.398: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1302): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
02-11 10:19:23.398: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1302):   in android.widget.EditText{b1e49448 VFED..CL .F....I. 179,489-589,548 #7f090001 app:id/password}
02-11 10:19:23.398: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1302):   0: sent at 1624812000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1624812, downTime=1624667, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
02-11 10:19:24.318: D/dalvikvm(1302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 153K, 6% free 3688K/3908K, paused 34ms, total 39ms
02-11 10:19:26.638: D/AndroidRuntime(1302): Shutting down VM
02-11 10:19:26.638: W/dalvikvm(1302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1afbba8)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Process: com.example.earchive, PID: 1302
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.example.earchive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-11 10:19:26.658: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is my way correctly? 
Thanks to all

Comment: you are making heavy/slow work on the main thread and thats probably the worst thing to do, if you want to get or send data from/to the web, or you need to do some slow work try moving to another thread.

Comment: Nope. I have other problem

Comment: I need to do this code at other class ?

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if you want to avoid this while making your work on the ui thread you have to set correctly the strictmode

Answer (score 1):

Its because you do network operations on main thread. Just do an AsyncTask and you will be fine

Comment: So i need to do other one class, than i need to do import and call method ?